# Identify command line an MSI was installed with

Tags: windows-installer, command-line-arguments

Is it possible to identify which command line an MSI was installed with?

For example i'm passing some custom property in MSI installatin command line. 
msiexec /i msi1.msi CUSTOMPROPERTY1="Help me!"

After a while i want to update msi1.msi with msi2.msi and want to pass same custom property to the msi2.msi installation command line.

Does the command lines stored anywhere?

The approach i see is to create a reg key in msi1.msi will store the CUSTOMPROPERTY1 value and create an AppSearch entry in msi2.msi to search for this reg entry. In my case i'm not able to use this approach. That is why seaching for other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct. Windows Installer doesn't persist properties for subsequent transactions so you have to do it yourself.  Here's a blog talking about it:

[The WiX toolset's "Remember Property" pattern.](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/5/2/the-wix-toolsets-remember-property-pattern)

Personally the above pattern doesn't go far enough.  What I do is I read the registry value into a second property and then use a series of conditionalized custom actions to only populate the main value if appropriate.   The goal is to enforce a property precedence in the following most to least order:

1. Value entered by the user via custom controls on a dialog in the UI sequence.
2. Value passed to the installer via the command line.
3. Value persisted from a previous installation.
4. Default value baked into the MSI.

Comment: Have looked the article. It describes same approach I've written about. 

So the only solution in my case is to create registry entries storing custom property values and acquiring it by using build-in AppSearch mechanism. Isn't it?

Comment: Or INI or XML or somewhere.  Personally I found it tedious to implement this for every single property so I wrote custom actions (SaveProperties and LoadProperties) that are driven by a property called PersistedProperties (PersistedProperties=SVCUSERNAME;SVCPASSWORD )  I also put some encryption logic in the custom action.

Comment: That makes sense. Could you please share the mechanism of identifying the property was passed in command line or located in MSI/MST? I’m actually do not need complete vbs listing, just an idea.

Comment: Read Registry -> TEMPPROP  Set PROP = TEMPPROP condition PROP null. Set PROP = DEFAULTPROP condition PROP null.  Schedule for UI and Execute sequence "run only once".  Things like that.

Answer (score 1):

*Advanced Installer* can also help you with the [Set persistent property](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-permanent-properties.html) option. On update you don't need to call or search for those properties, their custom values are fetched automatically from the registry.

Cheers

Comment: Thank you, but it could be done with any free MSI editor, no need to buy Advanced Installer. That's will take about 1 minute in Orca or InstEd to create a component with registry key, assign it to some feature and create an AppSearch record. If you read my post again you will see i haven't asked for advise in choosing packaging software. The question was about identifying command line an MSI was installed with.

Comment: It's good to know though. I've been wishing that InstallShield would implement this feature for years.

Comment: Yeap, Flexera vision on this is too advanced :)